# Create mean of each column and put it into the workspace

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

Below is my matlab code:

```
  for t=1:5
    data=[1 3 5 7 9;2 4 6 8 10];
    k(t)=mean(data(:,t));
    end
```

As a result,k(1)=1.5,k(2)=3.5, ... ,k(5)=9.5.
I want to create a result which combine all of them as shown in below:

Result=[1.5;3.5;5.5;7.5;9.5]

Any good idea to do that??Thanks.

Comment: Based on your comments on the answers you don't understand what you ask, or you explain it wrongly, -1.

Answer (score 2):

```
data=[1 3 5 7 9;2 4 6 8 10];
R = mean(data)';
```

Amended:

As was mentioned above, if this solution is not what you expected, I'm not really sure what your asking. From your title you mention 'put into the workspace'? Does this mean you want a variable for each value in 'R'? If so, try:

```
for i = 1:5    
    kk = R(i);
    % eval(sprintf('k%d = kk', i)); % better to avoid eval use assignin instead
    assignin('base',['K' sprintf('%d',i)],kk);
end
```

Comment: Thanks 4 your ans,,i know how to use the transpose, the question is i wan to know how to store it if must using for loop in this code.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use,

```
data = [1 3 5 7 9; 2 4 6 8 10];
k = mean( data );        % k = [1.5, 3.5, 5.5, 7.5, 9.5];
% To get a column vector use:
k = mean( data )';       % k = [1.5; 3.5; 5.5; 7.5; 9.5];
```

Check the documentation of [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks 4 your ans,,i know how to use the transpose, the question is i wan to know how to store it if must using for loop in this code.

Comment: @TonyYEe your question is not clear. Is the `for`-loop inside a function? See edit to Kate's answer if you want to create variables for each value. Based on the code you provided `Result == k'`. Can you provide a better description for the problem.